# Global variable for react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, global-variables

I don't know, how to use a global variable.

I want to make "this.props.topic.text" a global variable to use it on an other app of my project. How can I do that?

```js
export default class Topic extends Component {

  deleteThisTopic() {
    Topics.remove(this.props.topic._id);
  }

  test() {
  
  }
  render() {
    return (

      <Router>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <Link to="/sub"><li onClick={this.test.bind(this)}>{this.props.topic.text}  ARN:  {this.props.topic.arn}</li></Link>
        <Link to="/log"><button onClick={this.test.bind(this)}>S'inscrire</button></Link>
        <Link to="/"><button >Cacher</button></Link>
        <button onClick={this.deleteThisTopic.bind(this)}>Suprimer</button>
      </ul>

      <hr/>
      <Route exact path="/log" component={AppInscription}/>
      <Route exact path="/sub" component={AppSub}/>


    </div>
  </Router>
  );
  }
}

Topic.propTypes = {

  topic: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

Comment: It's not clear at all why you think you need a global variable. What is the relationship between the code you have posted and the question you have asked?

Comment: i have an other app on my project in which i need to use the variable returned by "this.props.topic.text". I think the only way to get this variable on my other app is to make her became global so my question is how to define a global variable in react and how i can use it ?

Comment: You can't really define properties as global in react but you can use a library like redux to have one single state for your entire application where you can access the object from different places.

Comment: I guess you might be right @Alex but if the OP is really talking about completely separate apps, then maybe they just want to write a value to a file. I still don't understand the requirement.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is a terrible idea, but probably the best/easiest way to use a global variable in React is to put it on the `window`. In a component you could do something like `window.topicText="some text"` and then access it via `window.topicText` everywhere else.

Ideally, if you have data, and in your case likely state, that you need to persist from component to component, you should look into something like [Redux](http://redux.js.org/) or [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/). I prefer Redux.

Comment: It works well. Can you explain me why it's a bad idea like?

Comment: @alpheonix Why would it be anything other than a bad idea to have a variable that is read/write accessible to absolutely everything in your application, just because you need it in a handful of places?

Comment: Yep. what @TomFenech said.

Comment: @Tom Fenech Is that the only drawback? Because it seems kinda tempting to work with "window". And if so, could you be more specific? why it is such a bad idea? Thanks =)

Comment: @Andri there is nothing React- or even JS-specific about my advice against using global variables - you will find many good answers on this site that discuss the subject. See also https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:
Declare your global variable before your main component App.js and pass this variable as props down the tree.

Parent.js

```
var myVar = {}

class MyComponent extends Component {

...
...
myVar = new Object();
...
...
render() {
   return <div>
                 \\ children
                 <MyLeftBranch myVar={myVar} />
                 <MyRightBranch myVar={myVar} />
              </div>
}
}

export default MyComponent;
```

child.js

```
class Child extends Component {
     { myVar } = this.props;
     \\use myVar
}
```

Answer (score 1):

App.js

```
// Since this.state is global from parent to child components
// This was the easiest solution I've found:

import React, { Component } from "react";
import firebase from "../config";

class App extends Component
 constructor(props) {
     super(props);

     // Set the key to the reference name
     // Assign value to firebase DB collection

     this.state = {
         roomsRef: firebase.firestore().collection("rooms")
     }
}

// reference it anywhere in the component:

componentDidMount() {
    this.getDb(this.state.roomsRef);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript + globalThis

```
//@ts-ignore TODO cleanup this debug output
globalThis.MY_NAMESPACED_NAME = { something: 'to inspect in the console' }
```

---

A bad idea for production code, but useful for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

```
To use a global variable, I found a below way : 

    Create a file :
    
    import React from "react";
    
    const AppContext = {};
    
    export default AppContext;
    
    then in App.js, update the value
    import AppContext from './AppContext';
    
    
    AppContext.username = uname.value;
    
    Now if you want the username to be used in another screen:
    
    import AppContext from './AppContext';
    
    AppContext.username to be used for accessing it.


I found another way also ,using localStorage to use it anywhere in the application :

1)Setting the value : 
  localStorage.setItem('username', <set the name>);

2)Getting the value :
localStorage.getItem("username")
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting.

Comment: Okies will do the same

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case, a good way to use global variables is **Context**. Basically, what a **Context** is doing, offers the possibility for every component to access a set of variables everywhere in the code. (Normally, the way variables are passed, is from parent to child)

For reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html