# I wanna make changes to a static array in one class from another react native

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

i'm trying to add product from my component PRODUCT to a static array in CART component but i keep getting an error
snippet from CART Component

```
export default class Cart extends Component{

    static products=[];
.....
```

snippet from PRODUCT Component

```
<Button style={{flex:1, height:30, alignContent:'center', backgroundColor:'#8ab465'}} 
                        onPress={()=>{
                            Cart.Products.push({
                                name:this.props.productName,
                                price:this.props.productPrice,
                            })
                        }}
```

ERROR:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating '_cart.Cart.Products')
onPress
   ......
```

how i can make changes to the array directly from the product Component

Comment: Are you using TypeScript?

Comment: In your Product component `Products` is uppercase, but in your Cart component it is lowercase... That being said, I would not recommend solving it this way as it is sort of counter to the React paradigm

Comment: yes i changed the name but still the same error @ken4z

Comment: I found the best solution is to use `AsyncStorage` to store my array and load it, in the appropriate place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are not using redux the best way to do this is

in the common ancestor of both the components create a state `{ products: [] }` and a handler to add a product to this state.

```
export default class Ancestor extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      products: []
    }
  }
  onAddProduct = (product) => {
    // make sure you do not mutate the state else your component
    // will not update
    this.setState({ products: [this.state.products, product] })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Cart products={this.props.products}/>
        <Product onAdd={this.onAddProduct}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

now in your product component you can use

```
export default class Product extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Button 
        onPress={() => this.props.onAdd({
          name: this.props.productName,
          price: this.props.productPrice
        })}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

this way your Cart component will rerender with the correct products when you add a new product

With this approach you will have to keep passing the props down from the common ancestor to the correct components. So the best approach is to use `Redux`

Comment: Thanks @Elroy
i will try your solution, in future i will change to redux

Answer (score 0):

There are quick and dirty ways to do this, but they will not do you any good. The right way is to use redux, define the cart object (not component) in redux store.

Then, both components, Cart and Products will use this store.

onPress of a product will fire an action that will add this product to the cart. The Cart component will access the cart in order to display its content.

This is a proper way (not the only proper way) to solve your problem. It will also serve you in complex projects.

A quick and dirty way will be to put it in the window. See: [Global variable for react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45080011/global-variable-for-react)

Comment: thanks @Rahamin
but i'm short in time and i didn't use redux in my project at all if there is any other way i can use it just using react-native

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this:

```
class Cart extends Component {
  products = [];

  handleSubmit = (name, price) => {
    const newItem = {
      name,
      price,
    };
    this.products.push(newItem)
  };

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.handleSubmit('productName', 120)}>Button</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Also, "you probably don't need Redux" most of the times, check these two amazing articles:

https://medium.com/@blairanderson/you-probably-dont-need-redux-1b404204a07f
https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367

Comment: Thanks @Vlad 
The logic behind my application is to add bunch of products to the cart and submit the array as an order, so i need to clean the array and start over in the next order