# What is the most performant method to access top level props in deep children or a config file?

Tags: reactjs

**Currently**

1. I have an item list built in React.
2. Each item has fields, and `field 1` can be edited by a form.
3. The `field 1` form allows you to link 2 items together.
4. The form takes in a config file that contains the list of items.

**Problem**

What is the most performant way to populate the config file with the list of items so that each form (when opened) can access the list of items?

1. My concern is that if I pass the list of items down through each item, it's a very heavy load on the app.
2. I have also read that declaring global variables (e.g. in `window.items`) is bad practice. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45081013/1730260

**Architecture**
[image]

Comment: have you tried using `context` ?

Comment: `My concern is that if I pass the list of items down through each item, it's a very heavy load on the app.` That is not correct, you are just passing reference to each component down the tree

Comment: @azium, I am aware of `context`, and know that I have options to populate `[items]` in each form, but my concern is building the most performant architecture.

Comment: @Rikin, so passing down context to potentially thousands of items, and potentially many levels of components, to populate them in `form 1` is the most performant solution? Better than declaring a global variable either in `window` or using `context`?

Comment: @Wronski my comment was related to your `heavy load` comment in your post. Context API is to avoid prop drilling like you would include passing props in each and every component. If you are using Redux then you can just `connect` any of the desired child component and have it pull desired value from the global `state` object.

Comment: @Rikin, do you know if props drilling is more performant and or a better pattern than using `context` API? or redux? I am not using redux, but would like to avoid adding another package if I can solve with native options.

Comment: @Wronski performance wise both are same thing, Context API is just a cleaner/newer approach that people can take. Since your architecture is based on multiple and deep child tree, Redux is more viable solution for you so that you dont have to pass prop to any undesired component and just pull from App state where needed directly by using `connect`. If you are talking about React's own implementation then Context API for cleaner approach but again perf wise both are same.

Comment: @Rikin, that's most of the answer that I was after i.e. connect vs prop drilling vs react all have the same performance. Do you want to post as an answer so I can close?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

performance wise both are same thing, Context API is just a cleaner/newer approach that people can take. Since your architecture is based on multiple and deep child tree, Redux is more viable solution for you so that you dont have to pass prop to any undesired component and just pull from App state where needed directly by using `connect`. If you are talking about React's own implementation then `Context API` for cleaner approach but again performance wise both are same.